# Nginx + NodeJS redirecting to port 80

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, digital-ocean

I am having issues redirecting my port 80 to 4000 where my nodejs application is running on my Digital Ocean Ubuntu Droplet. Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name my_site.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

When ever I head over to my droplet's IP on port 4000 the application loads successfully but not when I try on port 80.

Comment: Maybe you meant to put `proxy_pass http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:4000;` instead of using port *8080*?

Comment: my mistake, port 4000 is what I have in my file. edited the code segment above @Jawad

Comment: Did you restart the nginx service after editing the file? And is the `default` file symlinked to a file inside the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` folder?

Comment: yes i have symlinked the default file inside the /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder and restarted the nginx service but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a proxy_pass of port :8080 but you said your application is running on port 4000.
You need to tell nginx the correct port to proxy, (4000 instead of 8080)

Then you need to restart the nginx service `sudo service nginx restart`